# Ruby on rails, named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So for example i have non-restful named route:

```
get ':controller/:action/:juhu/:blabla', :as => "something"
```

and from **rake routes** i have following:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                  Controller#Action
something GET /:controller/:action/:juhu/:blabla(.:format) :controller#:action
```

**//Controller**

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
    def juhu_juhu
        # Will try to render juhu_juhu.html.erb
    end
end
```

**// View**

```
    <%= link_to "Get back", something_path %>
```

And i get error:

```
No route matches {:juhu=>"1", :blabla=>"neta", :controller=>"tests", :action=>"juhu_juhu"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

So what about this "missing required keys: [:id]"

So i assume that every restful routes must have **:id** by convention(am i right?), but why non-restful routes also must have **:id**(literally named :id), or something i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What is your rails version?

routes.rb

```
root 'tests#index'
get ':controller/:action/:juhu/:blabla', :as => "something"
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Get back", something_path %>
```

tests_controller.rb

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def juhu_juhu
  end
end
```

I try you example and I got this problem and check `127.0.0.1:3000` .

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tests"} missing required keys: [:juhu, :blabla]
```

The url `127.0.0.1:3000/tests/juhu_juhu/1/2` is success and could not have "missing required keys: [:id]" problem.

And I link to `127.0.0.1:3000/tests/juhu_juhu/1/neta` also success:

```
Started GET "/tests/juhu_juhu/1/neta" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-01 00:48:23 +0800
Processing by TestsController#juhu_juhu as HTML
  Parameters: {"juhu"=>"1", "blabla"=>"neta"}
  Rendered tests/juhu_juhu.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 82ms (Views: 66.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: @Srle Do you have anthor route in your application? Your non-restful named route didn't have `:id`, so I think the problem isn't in the non-restful named route.

Comment: literally i have just one route in application.

Comment: Did you link to this url `127.0.0.1:3000/tests/juhu_juhu/1/neta` ? @Srle